# Having trouble with sizing of password text field in React form

Tags: html, css, reactjs, forms

I'm in the midst of developing my first React application, which includes the Login form below:
[image]

For some reason, I'm having trouble with the sizing of the password field, which as you can see looks a **lot** smaller than the username field.  In my CSS file, I can (more) easily control the size/width of the username field, but strangely for me not the password field, even when specifying `type=password` (this *is* the input type of the password field).

Relevant CSS code:

```
  input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #55acf3;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  form {
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Is there something which I'm missing that I need to modify width/height of the password field as compared to a normal text field or is it a different (potentially underlying) issue in my code?

HTML Code:

```
                    <form>
                    <label>Username:</label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value={this.state['username']} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br />
                    <label>Password:</label><br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value={this.state['password']} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                    <br />
                    <Link to='/'><input type="submit" value="Log In" onClick={() => this.handleSubmit()} /></Link>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href='/register'><input type="button" value="Sign Up"/></a>
                    <br />
                    <a href='/'><input type="button" value="Back"/></a>
                    <br />
                    </form>
```

Comment: CSS looks fine.
Can you share just the snippet for password field. ( HTML/JSX )?

Comment: Added.  Sorry if it looks a little weird with the crazy large indent.

Comment: All of this looks fine. Can you inspect the element and check the computed styles for the input field for password. Your style looks fine, but , maybe something else is overriding your styles.

Comment: @AnmolBhardwaj like with F12 in browser?

Comment: yeah.
- right click on the element.
- click on inspect element
- then in the left styles menu , go to the computed styles tab.
- search for width and/or other properties and check what is the value there